# Unreal Engine 4 - which class spawned the shot?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

In Unreal Engine 4 I have two different classes (Player and Enemy) that spawn the same type of Actor (Shot). From within the newly created Shot, how can I find out which of those two classes spawned it?

I am sure there is a pretty straightforward answer to it, but I can't seem to phrase it properly when searching, as I am not getting any helpful hits.

Note: I have started digging into UE4 very recently, so it is quite possible that I have found the answer already but am just not sure what I am looking for. Or that I should simply have two different classes (Player Shot and Enemy Shot). Any help appreciated!

---

Edit: `GetInstigator()` gets me the values I expected but the description gives me the impression this is not necessarily what I am looking for: `The APawn that is responsible for damage done by the spawned Actor. (Can be left as NULL).`

Comment: You probably want to be using `AActor::Instigator` `/** Pawn responsible for damage and other gameplay events caused by this actor. */`.

Comment: Cheers, that seems to be what I was looking for after all :D

Answer (score 0):

If you're using BP, in the `Shot` class, create a variable (actor reference). When you spawn the actor, cast to the `Shot` reference, using the Return Value from the `SpawnActor` node as the object. After making this cast, SET the actor reference variable you created to the `Self` reference of what pawn spawned it.

Basically, what you are doing here is when the `Shot` is spawned, a reference to the pawn (player or enemy) is created within it. Hope this helps!

Comment: I was actually doing this through C++ but the principle is pretty much the same.
Thanks @Aaron !